# Renaming largest files that contain distinct sub strings of predetermined length in powershell

Tags: powershell, sorting, grouping, rename, filesize

I have been struggling with the following on powershell:

I have files with the first 3 characters referencing an ID and the rest of the filename contains a timestamp.

**ABC**.2019-10-23        SIZE: 5KB

**ABC**.2019-10-22        SIZE  7KB

**DEF**.2019-10-23        SIZE 4KB

**DEF**.2019-10-22        SIZE 11KB

Now the files are of different file sizes. What I would like to do is rename the largest files that include a distinct ID.

All the files are in the same folder and can be looped through without recursion.

After completing the task it should have renamed the files:

**ABC**.2019-10-22.old

**DEF**.2019-10-22.old

Because the first one is the largest file that contains the 3 character substring **ABC**

And the second file is the largest file that contains the substring **DEF**

This should be done to all the biggest files containing a distinct 3 character ID

Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Please _edit the question_ and describe with more details about the renaming: what exactly should be old and new names? Perhaps picking short filenames for sample data would help, as trying to see what the GUIDs are about is confusing.

Comment: Hello I edited the question as you asked @vonPryz.

Comment: use `Group-Object` with a calculated grouping target [the 1st 3 chars], sort each group by `.Length`, then rename the  largest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Lee_Daily](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3080908/lee-dailey) has provided the outline of a solution in a comment:

> use `Group-Object` with a calculated grouping target [the first 3 chars], sort each group by `.Length`, then rename the largest.

To put this into concrete terms:

```
Get-ChildItem -File | 
  Group-Object { $_.Name -replace '\..+' } | 
    ForEach-Object { 
      $_.Group | Sort-Object Length -Descending | Select-Object -First 1 |
        Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name + '.old' } -WhatIf
    }
```

<sup>`-WhatIf` *previews* the operation. Remove it once you're sure it will do what you want.</sup>

- `Get-ChildItem -File` enumerates all files in the current directory (adapt as needed).
- The `Group-Object` call groups the files by their names' first `.`-separated token (e.g., `ABC`, `DEF`)

  - `$_.Name -replace '\..+'` uses a [regular expression](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions) to effectively remove everything starting with the first literal `.` char. from the input string (file name) - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40683667/45375) for more information about the `-replace` operator; e.g., 
    `'ABC.More.Tokens' -replace '\..+'` yields `'ABC'`
- The `ForEach-Object` call processes each resulting group (`.Group`):

  - The `Sort-Object` call sorts descending by file size (`.Length`).
  - The `Select-Object -First 1` then selects only the first - and therefore largest - file.

    - Note: In PowerShell *Core* you could combine the `Sort-Object` and `Select-Object` calls to `Sort-Object -Top 1`
  - Finally, the `Rename-Item` renames the file by appending `.old` to the existing name.